# How to get distinct values from a table for a particular column?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I had a problem in retrieving the Distinct values from my MySQL DB from a table from a particular column. I have a table in which i have repeated values, so while retrieving the distinct values am not getting distinct as am trying to retrieve the ID and Marks field.

Here is the table

[image]

So here am trying to get the distinct values from Total Marks into a dropdownlist box using Asp.net and i need to get student id also for further process.

I am trying with a query as below:

`Select Distinct TotalMarks,Student_id from studenttable`;

Is this correct query?
I need to get the output in dropdownlist as distinct values of TotalMarks and ID.

Comment: There are multiple `Student_id` for the same `total marks` for 80 and 90, Which `Student_id` you want to select for each one?

Comment: No, this is not the correct query. Tell us more about what do you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this way:

```
Select Distinct TotalMarks,Student_id from studenttable group by Stuident_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is, if student 1 and student 2 have total marks 80. And you want to fetch only one of them (distinct total marks), which one is it?

Anyway the query would look like this:

```
SELECT TotalMarks, MIN(Student_id) AS Student_id FROM studenttable GROUP BY TotalMarks;
```

This query would fetch 1st student with such Total marks from each group. If you want the last one just change the aggregate function to MAX

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT MAX(Student_id),TotalMarks 
FROM studenttable
GROUP BY TotalMarks
```